# VBA Xpath Wildcard For Letters

Tags: vba, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   <price>44.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="5691">
            <PublisherLocation>Los Angeles</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor fName="Gambardella">
            <StoreLocation>Store B</StoreLocation>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
<book id="Adventure">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   <price>5.95</price>
   <misc>
        <Publisher id="4787">
            <PublisherLocation>New York</PublisherLocation>
        </Publisher>
        <PublishedAuthor Name="Ralls">
            <StoreLocation>Store B</StoreLocation>
        </PublishedAuthor>
    </misc>
</book>
</catalog>
```

The path to **PublishedAuthor** is the same for both books with the exception of one character. Is it possible to set a wildcard for this character so that it will accept either XPath?

`<catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor[@fName=]/`

Yields the exact same result as:

`<catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor[@Name=]/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attribute name can be either `Name` or `fName` then you can use:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim n

    doc.LoadXML Range("a1").Value

    Set n = doc.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor[@Name='Ralls']|" & _
                            "/catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor[@fName='Ralls']")

    Debug.Print n.Length '>> 2

End Sub
```

There's no wildcard available for attribute names.

Comment: Thanks! But what if it was a node AFTER the attribute? From the sample above, say something like `<catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor[@fName=]/StoreLocation/` and `<catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor[@fName=]/StoreLocations/` Where we have StoreLocation and StoreLocation**s**

Comment: Sorry, I meant something more like `<catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor/area/StoreLocation/` and `<catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthors/area/StoreLocation/` where there is no direct wild attribute, but inbetween there is a node that slightly differrs (in this case, **PublishedAuthors** and **PublishedAuthor**)

Answer (score 1):

There is no wildcard specifically for letter in XPath. As you probably already realized, the wildcard work for the entire names (element name or attribute name). To match partially in xpath, you may want to consider `starts-with()` and `substring()` functions.

Possible alternative for this specific case is using `or` operator which will save you from writing the same path twice, like when using union (`|`) operator :

```
/catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor[@fName or @Name]
```

And regarding your comment, you can use `starts-with()` check against node's `name()` like so :

```
/catalog/book/misc/*[starts-with(name(), 'PublishedAuthor')]/area/StoreLocation
```

Comment: Interesting. I could also technically do `<catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor/area/[contains[name(),'StoreLocation']/` or even `<catalog/book/misc/PublishedAuthor/area/[ends-with(name(),'Location']/` correct?

Comment: `contains(name(),'StoreLocation')` should also work, but `ends-with()` maybe not because it is xpath 2.0 function (AFAIK, most xpath engine/library implements xpath 1.0 only). For reference: [xpath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Comment: Sorry for another question, but I'm having an issue with my context: `Set loc = pn.SelectSingleNode("misc/PublishedAuthor/contains(name(),'StoreLocation')")`  VBA does not seem to like the brackets in this case, and when I remove the brackets VBA does not seem to like the word **contains**. Any idea why? :( Also, I noticed that a lot of others online don't use "quotes" when declaring their XPath, is that just for demonstration purposes?